# Books for proving the hopf invariant is a homomorphism.

Tags: reference-request

Books for proving that the Hopf invariant is a homomorphism. I need to see many proofs of this, could someone recommend some books to me please?

Comment: there is a movie with Ben Affleck called The Fear of All Sums

Comment: Ok thanks for clarification @WillJagy

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A somewhat recent [question](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/4049717/) asked about the proof of this fact in I.M. James' "Note on cup-products".  In one of the comments to my answer to that question I pointed out that Mosher-Tangora's book also contains a proof.